# How to pass alias into aws scheduled lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an aws lambda function and it runs on a timer that is built into the properties of the lambda.  How can I pass in an alias so I can run a particular version(the exact version will change per release cycle, thus, an alias is what I want to have in the configuration.)

From my template:

```
Resources:
  MyUpdateFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaFunctionName
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python2.7
      CodeUri: .
      Events:
        Timer:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: "rate(30 minutes)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RAW CloudFormation parts inside your SAM template.
There your can provide an explicit ARN of your target. In the ARN just add the `:123` to specify that you are running version 123. Or `:$ALIAS` to specify one.

```
Type: AWS::Events::Rule
Properties: 
  Name: Some Test Event Rule
  ScheduleExpression: rate(30 minutes)
  Targets: 
    - 
      Arn: YOUR_LAMBDA_ARN:$GREEN
      Id: SOME_READABLE_ID_OF_RULE
```

More info about the ScheduledRules in CloudFormation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nikolay, is this supposed to be another resource entry in the same template.yaml file, or deployed as it's own stack, or.. something else?

Comment: Just another Resource entry.